# How to connect Datagrip with AWS Athena using an assumed role?

Tags: aws, datagrip

I am able to make Athena queries through the AWS CLI. This requires me to assume a role first (I use `awsume`). The role requires MFA.

Now I want to configure Datagrip for this as well. However there are two options for authenticating:

- User/pass - I can put in my AWS key ID and secret, but I think it would fail without the MFA token as well (there is no field for it in Datagrip 2021.1).
- AWS profile - I figured out what to put into "Profile" - it's the `source_profile` in my role's profile in my `~/.aws/config`. However, I can't figure out what to put under `User`.

If I put in:

- The name of the role's profile
- The name of the role
- The ARN of the role
- My AWS username
  They all fail with the error:

> The specified database user/password combination is rejected: [HY000][100071] [Simba]AthenaJDBC An error has been thrown from the AWS Athena client. User: arn:aws:iam::[NUMBER]:user/[MYUSERNAME] is not authorized to perform: athena:ListDataCatalogs [Execution ID not available]
>
> com.simba.athena.amazonaws.services.athena.model.AmazonAthenaException: User: arn:aws:iam::[NUMBER]:user/[MYUSERNAME] is not authorized to perform: athena:ListDataCatalogs (Service: AmazonAthena; Status Code: 400; Error Code: AccessDeniedException; Request ID: [UUID]; Proxy: null

I get this same error, with my username, even if I put in the role as a `User` in the Datagrip dialog box.

Comment: Have you read the article Amazon article [How can I use my IAM role credentials or switch to another IAM role when connecting to Athena using the JDBC driver?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/athena-iam-jdbc-driver/) where the process is well described?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up solving this by using a named profile in credentials.

awsume has an option to write the credentials to the file: `awsume -o default role-profile-name` will write them as `[default]` in `~/.aws/credentials`.

Then in Datagrip, I configured the connection to use `default` as the profile. The username is apparently not used and can be anything (at least in my case).

For details, see https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/athena-iam-jdbc-driver/